# Pascal - hard-coding data in array - shortcut

Tags: arrays, pascal, freepascal, static-initialization

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
T[1]:=5;
T[2]:=3;
.
.
.
T[9]:=20;
```

Is there a shortcut to achieving this where I can assign the values in a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find this in any of the documentations but I tried this and it works!

Here's the method used with a complete example:

```
Program StrangeArray;

Var T: Array[1..5] of Integer = (554,434,144,343,525);
    x:integer;

Begin
For x:=1 to 5 Do
    Begin
    Writeln(T[x]);

    End;

End.
```

Hope this is useful for others as well.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Thank you for this info... This came in a little too late but it's a good find. The docs should have had this under arrays and not under initializing variables... +1 for your efforts :)